# subfigure global counting caption

Tags: captions, subfloats

I would like to keep subfigure count my figures globally and label them continuesly.

This is the way it is:

[Fig 1] 
[Fig 2] 
[Fig 3a Fig 3b] 
[Fig 4]

And that is the way I want it:

[Fig 1]
[Fig 2]
[Fig 3 Fig 4]
[Fig 5]

I think it shouldn't be too hard, but well, I need help :)
(another package is not an option! I want to do this with subfigure)

Thanks alot

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: what you want is the standard behaviour _without_ subfigure. So just don't use that paclage and use two `\caption` commands in the third `figure` environment.